# $_SERVER['HOME'] doesn't show the correct value nginx ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I have a nginx server with php5-fpm on ubuntu 14.

when I echo `$_SERVER['HOME']` it return back `/var/www`

my web files located in `/usr/share/nginx/html`

obviously it's not my home directory
if i type `~/` in the terminal I can get the home directory that is `/home/myname`

I couldn't find where this information set and why it set wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_SERVER['HOME'] returns the home path of the current user.

If nginx is running as (for example) www-data, then you'll get the home-directory of www-data.

I guess that you need $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Answer (score 0):

return value is root of the user that nginx is running under it, usually it's www-data.

```
string get_current_user ( void )
```

you can confirm the current user with [get_current_user](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php)